# Ratio of TableView contentoffset with respect to cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift3

I have a tableview on each cell their scrollview. I have to set cell scrollview offset on table scroll.How we make ration of tableconentent offset with cell Please help I am newer in iOS. I m using `JbParralax`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

  let indexpath =  table.indexPathsForVisibleRows

  let a : Int = (indexpath?.count)! - 1

  for i in 0...a {
    let  b = indexpath?[i]
    let cell = table.cellForRow(at: b!) as? Custum
    cell?.myScrollView.contentOffset.y = table.contentOffset.y
  }

}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 6
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "Custum"
    var cell: Custum! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? Custum
    if cell == nil {
      var nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Custum", owner: self, options: nil)!

      cell = nib[0] as? Custum
    }

    //cell.myScroll
    cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named:banner[indexPath.row])
    return cell
  } 
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want, can you please elaborate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259059/objective-c-func-call-on-swift-3

Comment: I am finding demo JbParralax Cell but in objective c when i am using swift

Comment: it give error.Please help

Comment: https://github.com/maxep/MXParallaxHeader are you using this library ?