# Call Objective-C function in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am embeding `JBParallaxCell`, a `UITableViewCell` subclass. I want to call a function:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Get visible cells on table view.
    NSArray *visibleCells = [self.tableView visibleCells];

    for (JBParallaxCell *cell in visibleCells) {
        [cell cellOnTableView:self.tableView didScrollOnView:self.view];
    }
}
```

I converted this code to Swift:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleCells = table.visibleCells
    var cells : JBParallaxCell?

    for cells in visibleCells {
        cells(on: table, didScrollOn: self.view)
        // cells.cellOnTableView(tableView: table, didScrollOn: self.view)
    }
}
```

They give error call not function of `UITableViewCell`

Comment: can not call function of Uitableviewcell

Comment: which error you get? Post your error

Comment: Did you convert `[cell cellOnTableView:self.tableView didScrollOnView:self.view];` to swift ?

Comment: @J.Koush yes sir..

Comment: @J.Koush already converted u can see  cells(on: table, didScrollOn: self.view)

Comment: they give error can not call non function of uitableview cell

Answer (score 1):

If your tableview outlet is called `table`, then you'd could do:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in table.visibleCells {
        if let cell = cell as? JBParallaxCell {
            cell.cell(on: table, didScrollOn: view)
        }
    }
}
```

Or, equivalent:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in table.visibleCells {
        (cell as? JBParallaxCell)?.cell(on: table, didScrollOn: view)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use a `flatMap { $0 as? JBParallaxCell }` probably.

Comment: Yep, that works, too. My point (other than the obvious `obj.cell(on:didScrollOn:)` Swift 3 signature for that Objective-C method) is that I don't like `let visible = table.visible as? [JBParallaxCell]` pattern, because it falls apart if one of the cells happens to not be parallax cell. The `flatMap` solves that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `[cell cellOnTableView:self.tableView didScrollOnView:self.view];` to swift and add it in JBParallaxCell. 
I converted it myself

```
      func cellOnTableView(tableView: UITableView, didScrollOn view: UIView) {
         let rectInSuperview: CGRect = tableView.convert(frame, to: view)

         let distanceFromCenter: Float = Float(frame.height / 2 - rectInSuperview.minY)
         let difference: Float = Float(parallaxImage.frame.height - frame.height);
         let  move: Float = (distanceFromCenter / Float(view.frame.height)) * difference

         var imageRect: CGRect = parallaxImage.frame
         imageRect.origin.y = CGFloat(move - (difference / 2))
         self.parallaxImage.frame = imageRect
}
```

And change this line `let visibleCells = table.visibleCells` to

```
if let visibleCells = table.visibleCells as? JBParallaxCell
```

Comment: sir when i am coverted this in swift it give me error Binart operator /  and - can not apply operand of type Float and CGFLOAT

Comment: @PallaviSinghal I've updated the code you needed to cast `CGFloat` to `Float`.

Comment: @Rob thanks for pointing out, I got distracted while writing the code. now it's updated.

Comment: `distanceFromCenter` still isn't quite right. You refer to `frame.height` where you meant `view.frame.height` (where `view` is the parameter passed to this method). Also, I'd still suggest the Swift 3 method signature `func cell(on tableView: UITableView, didScrollOn view: UIView) { ... }` if you wanted to follow the original (poorly named) signature. Personally, I'd rename it entirely, e.g. to something like `func didScroll(on tableView: UITableView, within view: UIView) { ... }`.